# I'm trying for if or else with Changecolor. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong

Tags: perl, cgi

That's a color Button with changing red or green. And here's there a function for the click button by color change. But 2 times click, then not more a change color. It stay same color of green, it can't further change to red button. I'm trying for the "while, do, or". But I don't understand. Please help me.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

my $cgi = new CGI;
my $setcolor;
my $newcolor;
my $changecolor;
```

Here's a img/url button:

```
print "<td><a href=\"../max.cgi?changecolor=$newcolor\" target=\"_parent\"><img src=\"http://../images/ts${setcolor}.png\"/></a></td>\n";
```

Here's a Function:

```
if ($cgi->param('changecolor')) {
    $setcolor=$cgi->param('changecolor');
    if ($setcolor=='red') {
        $newcolor='gre';
    }
}
else {
    $setcolor='gre';
    $newcolor='red';
}
```

And another:

```
if ($cgi->param('changecolor')) {
    $setcolor=$cgi->param('changecolor');
    if ($setcolor=='red') {
        $newcolor='gre';
        while($setcolor=='gre') {
            $newcolor='red';
        }
    }
}
else {
    $setcolor='gre';
    $newcolor='red';
}
```

Comment: Are you using `strict` and `warnings`? Have you declared your variables `$setcolor` and `$newcolor`?

Comment: Your `$changecolor` should be `changecolor`.

Comment: @simbabque Yes of course with strict and warnings.

Comment: @reinierpost Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your function should be like this:

```
if ($cgi->param('changecolor'))
{
    $setcolor=$cgi->param('changecolor');
    if ($setcolor eq 'red')
    {
        $newcolor='gre';
    }
    elsif ($setcolor eq 'gre')
    {
        $newcolor='red';
    }
}
```

Comment: I was going to say much the same. Can I suggest that it probably isn't `==` we need here though?

Comment: @simbabque: I was editing but you were faster. Thanks!

Comment: @Markus `use strict` is complaining because you did not _declare_ `$setcolor` in the same scope as you used it. Did you use the code from this answer directly, or did you add `my` inside of the `if { }`? Looks like it was declared in a smaller scope than where you used it.

Comment: @simbabque I will edit up again. with `my` and `use strict` and `if`

Comment: @serenesat Thank you very much! But I write other code. 
`if ($cgi->param($colortask)) {
    $setcolor=$cgi->param($colortask);
    if ($setcolor eq 'yel') {
        $newcolor='red';
    }
}
else {
 $setcolor='gre';
 $newcolor='yel';
}` That's work for me! But thank you again! :-)